# How to populate/link data in mongoose/mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have 3 Schema defined:

```
var ChangeSetSchema = new Schema({
    id: String,
    ...
    workitems: [{  type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'WorkItem' }]
});

var WorkItemSchema = new Schema({
    id: String,
    ...
});
```

The ids inside the array 'workitems' in 'ChangeSetSchema' will be the same as the 'id' of a 'WorkItemSchema'.
I am wondering how do I have to save the data, for example the Changeset schema:

```
router.route('/changeset')

    .post(function(req, res) {
        Changeset.find({ id: req.body.id }, function(err, changeset) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            } else {
                var changeset = new Changeset();
                changeset.id = req.body.id;
                changeset.url = req.body.url;
                changeset.author = req.body.author;
                changeset.createddate = req.body.createddate;
                changeset.comment = req.body.comment;
                //changeset.workitems = req.body.workitems;
                changeset.save(function(err) {
                    if (!err) {
                        Changeset.find({})
                            .populate('workitems')
                            .exec(function(error, changesets) {
                                console.log(JSON.stringify(changesets, null, "\t"));
                                res.send('1');
                            })
                    }
                });
            }

        });
    })
```

Do I have to create and save the 'WorkItems' objects everytime I save a 'ChangeSet' or can I just tell mongodb that those two are linked?

I am using Express.js, full code here: https://github.com/Trigu/ReleaseNotes/tree/master

Comment: Every time you insert a ChangeSet, you insert a new WorkItem? Each WorkItem belongs to only one ChangeSet?

Answer (score 0):

```
router.route('/changeset')

    .post(function(req, res) {
        Changeset.findOne({ id: req.body.id }, function(err, changeset) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            } else {
                //get Id before new
                if(changeset){
                var changesetWorkitemsId=changeset.workitems;
                 }

                //creating new object here
                var changeset = new Changeset();
                changeset.id = req.body.id;
                changeset.url = req.body.url;
                changeset.author = req.body.author;
                changeset.createddate = req.body.createddate;
                changeset.comment = req.body.comment;

                //set Id
                if(changesetWorkitemsId){
                changeset.workitems = changesetWorkitemsId;
                }else{
                 changeset.workitems = req.body.workitems;
                }  
                changeset.save(function(err) {
                    if (!err) {
                        Changeset.find({})
                            .populate('workitems')
                            .exec(function(error, changesets) {
                                console.log(JSON.stringify(changesets, null, "\t"));
                                res.send('1');
                            })
                    }
                });
            }

        });
    })
```